# on clicking a button is there a way to check what image is inside a Div?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so i have two Div elements (70px by 70px) and two images, the images have the HTML5 drag and drop functionality and can be dragged into the Div boxes.

What i want to do is when the images have been dragged into the div boxes and a button is then clicked, i want the border of the div boxes to change color depending on what image is inside the Div.

Is there a way to do this using Javascript?. The images have ID's so is it possible to write a function that uses that?

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
#Drop1 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}
#Drop2 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");

    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId"; 
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="Drop1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">  </div>
    <div id="Drop2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
    <img id="drag1" src="forward.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="64" height="64">
    <img id="drag2" src="left.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="64" height="64">
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you would like to accomplish?

JS

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html"),
      nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true),
      type = nodeCopy.src;

  nodeCopy.id = "newId"; 
  ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);

  if(type.indexOf(".png") !== -1) {
    ev.target.className = 'red-border';
  } else if(type.indexOf(".jpg") !== -1) {
    ev.target.className = 'green-border';
  } else {
    ev.target.className = 'gray-border';
  }

}
```

CSS

```
#Drop1 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}
#Drop2 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}

#Drop1.red-border,
#Drop2.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#Drop1.green-border,
#Drop2.green-border {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#Drop1.gray-border,
#Drop2.gray-border {
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfxqukPSabEpCteJeOzr?p=preview)

Updated version with button

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html"),
      nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true),
      type = nodeCopy.src;

  nodeCopy.id = "newId"; 
  ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}

function checkImages() {
  var drop1Elem = document.getElementById('Drop1'),
      drop2Elem = document.getElementById('Drop2');

  if(drop1Elem.childNodes.length >= 1) {
    if(drop1Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item1') {
      drop1Elem.className = 'red-border';
    } else if(drop1Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item2') {
      drop1Elem.className = 'green-border';
    } else {
      drop1Elem.className = 'gray-border';
    }
  }

  if(drop2Elem.childNodes.length >= 1) {
    if(drop2Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item1') {
      drop2Elem.className = 'red-border';
    } else if(drop2Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item2') {
      drop2Elem.className = 'green-border';
    } else {
      drop2Elem.className = 'gray-border';
    } 
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfxqukPSabEpCteJeOzr?p=preview)

Comment: Hi KungWaz it's sort of what I'm after..however is there a way to make this happen when a button is clicked instead? also the conditions are using image file formats..could i not use the image ID's instead?

Comment: Yes, move the code i wrote to a button and add a click event on it that checks for certain elems inside your drop elems and then set the border class or a text output depending on the ID of the elem.

Comment: See my updated answer, just change from border to a text field if you want that ;)

Comment: That's brilliant KungWaz thanks a lot :)..life saver.